# How does zend_refcounted used in zval?

Tags: php

I cant uderstand purpose of `zend_refcounted  *counted;` field in `union _zend_value` (which is part of `zval`). When does it used?

```
typedef union _zend_value {
    zend_long         lval;             /* long value */
    double            dval;             /* double value */
    zend_refcounted  *counted;
    zend_string      *str;
    zend_array       *arr;
    zend_object      *obj;
    zend_resource    *res;
    zend_reference   *ref;
    zend_ast_ref     *ast;
    zval             *zv;
    void             *ptr;
    zend_class_entry *ce;
    zend_function    *func;
    struct {
        uint32_t w1;
        uint32_t w2;
    } ww;
} zend_value;
```

I know that every structure that represent non-scalar values like `zend_string`, `zend_array` etc. starts from `zend_refcounted_h` structure. So `zend_refcounted` too, but there is nothing else...

```
typedef struct _zend_refcounted zend_refcounted;
/*...*/
struct _zend_refcounted {
    zend_refcounted_h gc;
};
```